# SQL CASE WHEN (1=1) What is the 1=1 doing?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL statement that I did not write and I am trying to get my head around it.

```
CASE
    WHEN (1 = 1) THEN A.AMT
    WHEN (A.ACC_NO = '1') THEN A.AMT - 100000000
    WHEN (A.ACC_NO = '2') THEN A.AMT - 100000000
    WHEN (A.ACC_NO = '3') THEN A.AMT - 100000000
    WHEN (A.ACC_NO = '4') THEN A.AMT - 100000000
    WHEN (A.ACC_NO = '5') THEN A.AMT - 100000000
    WHEN (A.ACC_NO = '6') THEN A.AMT - 100000000
    ELSE A.FACE_AMT
END AS TRUE_AMT,
```

Can someone please explain what the (1=1) is doing please?

From researching this online my interpretation is that 1=1 means always true, so this would mean the case statement would always return the amt field?

However this doesn't seem to make sense as this would mean none of the other conditions would ever be met?

Comment: it's exactly as you think

Comment: Some tired programmer short-circuited the case expression, got the expected result and forgot to do a proper code change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is placeholder for always true(typical usage is for debug/testing):

```
CASE
    WHEN (1 = 1) THEN A.AMT
    WHEN (A.ACC_NO = '1') THEN A.AMT - 100000000
    WHEN (A.ACC_NO = '2') THEN A.AMT - 100000000
    WHEN (A.ACC_NO = '3') THEN A.AMT - 100000000
    WHEN (A.ACC_NO = '4') THEN A.AMT - 100000000
    WHEN (A.ACC_NO = '5') THEN A.AMT - 100000000
    WHEN (A.ACC_NO = '6') THEN A.AMT - 100000000
    ELSE A.FACE_AMT
END AS TRUE_AMT,  


-- entire case is the same as:
A.AMT AS TRUE_AMT
```

Answer (score 2):

You would have to ask the person who wrote the code.  As you correctly point out, the code is preventing the later conditions from taking effect.

I might speculate that someone is writing the code and you are looking at a snapshot during development.  Or, they changed it from the full `case` expression and want to test the code before deleting the more detailed expressions.